# Cambiar el color de un boton permanentemente al hacer click

Tags: c#

Sé como hacer para que cambie el color,pero cuando cierro el programa el cambio no se guarda. Quisiera que el cambio pueda verse cuando abra otra vez el programa. 
El código que use fue este:

```
private void btnA100_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue);

        ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
        txtNHabit.Text = "A100";
    }
```

Comment: Usas windows forms o wpf? cómo lo haces que no te funciona? completa la pregunta porfavor!

Comment: Perdón por no especificar, y sí, es en windows form.

Comment: donde ejecutas ese código? tu problema es que lo estas ejecutando en el lugar incorrecto

Comment: Dentro del botón, por así decirlo

Comment: a que te referis con dentro del botón? estas creando tu propio tipo de botón?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta agregando eso porfavor

Comment: Ya lo cambie, asi fue como lo hice

Comment: Windows Forms no guarda cambios, todo lo hace en memoria, eso lo debes hacer tu en tu código.

Comment: Ah..hay algún tema que pueda buscar para saber como hacer eso?

Comment: @DarianGanz pero si quieres que aplique siempre cambialo al evento Load del form, si pones el codigo en el Click solo aplicara si ejecutas ese evento, no es un tema de guardar o no, es sobre que accion defines ese codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema se esta dando debido a que estas modificando la estética de tus botones en el lugar incorrecto.

El método `btnA100_Click` se ejecuta únicamente al momento de hacer click en algún botón (asumo `btnA100`).

Si lo que buscas es que se pinte al iniciar, podes hacerlo usando, ya sea el constructor de tu formulario, o el evento `Load` del mismo.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{              
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Acá podes pintarlo de la manera que lo haces.
        }
}
```

o también, como te comentaba arriba, podes suscribir el formulario al evento `Load`, por ejemplo

```
this.Load += Form1_Load1; //Asumiendo que this referencia a tu Form
```

y luego en lo pintas en el método asociado al evento

```
private void Form1_Load1(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          //Aca podes pintarlo de la manera que lo haces.
      }
```

Espero haber aclarado tus dudas.

Comment: Gracias! Pero si quisiera que el                                                                                                   
 private void   Form1_Load1(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          //Aca podes pintarlo de la manera que lo haces.
      }                                                                                                                       Solo cargará el cambio de color si se hizo click al boton?

Comment: @DarianGanz ese evento se ejecuta al momento de iniciar cargar el formulario

Comment: Es que si pongo que se cambie de color,lo hace. Pero lo cambia asi no se halla hecho click. Solo debe cambiar y permanecer asi, si se le hizo click

Comment: @DarianGanz por qué aceptaste esta respuesta si no responde a tu pregunta?