# Cargar cambios solo si se hizo click en el boton

Tags: c#

Windows form 
Quisiera que si se hizo click en un botón este cambie de color , y que cuando se cierre el programa, vuelva a mostrarse pero con el color cambiado. Solamente si se hizo click en él.

```
private bool Clicked;
private void btnA100_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clicked = true;
        this.btnA100.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
        txtNHabit.Text = "A100";

    }
   private void frmRegistrar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Clicked==true)
        {
            this.btnA100.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
        }

        //this.btnA101.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;

    }
```

Comment: Para eso debes persistir la informacion del valor Clicked en algun lado, por ejm: un archivo, una base de datos etc.

Comment: Lo guardo en un archivo, y cuando se vuelva abrir el programa que este lea este archivo?

Comment: Estas en lo correcto, puedes guardalo en un archivo, y cuando vuelvas abrir el programa obtienes el valor ya guardado.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Cambiar el color de un boton permanentemente al hacer click](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/216546/cambiar-el-color-de-un-boton-permanentemente-al-hacer-click)

Answer (score 0):

Podrias persistir el color en la configuracion de la aplicacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Using Settings in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa730869(v=vs.80))

Entonces cuando pulsas el boton asignas a la configuracion que color se asigna

```
private void btnA100_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //resto codigo
   Properties.Settings.Default.myColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void frmRegistrar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   btnA100.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.myColor;
}
```

solo recuperas el que tienes en la configuracion

Esta claro que por defecto en la configuracion debes asignar el color que quieras ver cuando no se presiono el boton, siempre podras editar con el notepad el .config para cambiar sin necesidad de recompilar

Comment: Aun así el boton no fue presionado me muestra el color que solo debe aparecer cuando este si fue presionado

Comment: el color esta definido en la configuracion, cuando lo defines por primera vez debes poner el color original del boton, solo asi al presionar el boton lo cambiara y seguira asi el resto del tiempo, salvo que edites con el notepad el config y lo cambies