# Salvar el color de una etiqueta

Tags: c#, windows-forms

quisiera hacer un Using Saving de color cuando un usuario haga un cambio de color en las label y al cerrar el programa no se cambie el color que el usuario ha escogido

he creado un Using Settings desde la configuracion de VisualStudio

tengo ese codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
uusing System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Color.Properties;

namespace Color
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

        {
            lblTeclado.ForeColor = colorDialog1.Color;
        }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTeclado.ForeColor = ((Color)Settings.Default["Color"]);
    }

    private void lblTeclado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default["Color"] = this.ForeColor;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Has pensado en guardar el color seleccionado en un ficherito? Y al arrancar el programa lo lees. Lo podrías hacer también con BBDD pero montar una BBDD para almacenar sólo un valor... veo más sencillo lo del fichero.

Comment: Esto posiblemente fue respondido en [persistir el color en la configuracion de la aplicacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216708/107347)